# Exchanging integrals with inner products with kernel mean embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, kernel-trick, kernel-smoothing, measure-theory

I am doing some reading on kernel mean embeddings. In particular I am reading the survey paper by [Muandet et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09522). On page 27 (Section 3.1) the authors begin a gentle introduction to kernel mean embeddings based on Dirac measures $\delta_{\mathbf{x}}(\cdot)$. Of course we have the familiar property that

$$
\int f(\mathbf{t})d\delta_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{t}) = f(\mathbf{x})
$$

for any measurable function $f$. The authors use this fact along with the reproducing property of reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces (such as $\mathcal{H}$) to conclude:

$$
\int f(\mathbf{t})d\delta_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{t}) = 
\int \langle f, k(\mathbf{t}, \cdot) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}d\delta_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{t}) =
\left\langle f, \int k(\mathbf{t}, \cdot)d\delta_{\mathbf{x}}(t)\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} = \langle f, k(\mathbf{x}, \cdot)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}
$$

where $k$ is the kernel function associated with $\mathcal{H}$. In this sense $k(\mathbf{x}, \cdot)$ is an embedding of the measure $\delta_{\mathbf{x}}$ in $\mathcal{H}$. **My question regards the second equality. How is this step rigorously justified?** Intuitively, I understand that this step is similar to using linearity to move a sum inside an inner product but I am not sure how a similar logic is justified here with the integral?

EDIT: This thought arose to me as I was writing this question so I have included it as an edit. Is this a case of first taking $k(\mathbf{t}, \cdot)$ as a simple function so that the integral changes to a sum? Then perhaps a limiting argument gets you the general case?